# request-reply with akka-camel and ActiveMQ

Tags: scala, apache-camel, activemq-classic, akka

Update: It would seem that an even simpler test case is not working: just trying to send a message from an ActiveMQ producer to an ActiveMQ consumer via the in-process broker.  Here is the code:

```
val brokerURL = "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"
val connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL)
val connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
val session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val queue = session.createQueue("foo.bar")
val producer = session.createProducer(queue)
val consumer = session.createConsumer(queue)
val message = session.createTextMessage("marco")

producer.send(message)
val resp = consumer.receive(2000)
assert(resp != null)
```

---

I'm trying to implement a very simple request-reply pattern using akka-camel.  Here's my (testbench) code which is trying to use activeMQ directly to send a message and expect a response:

```
val brokerURL = "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"

// create in-process broker, session, queue, etc...
val connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL)
val connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
val session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val queue = session.createQueue("myapp.somequeue")
val producer = session.createProducer(queue)
val tempDest = session.createTemporaryQueue()
val respConsumer = session.createConsumer(tempDest)
val message = session.createTextMessage("marco")
message.setJMSReplyTo(tempDest)
message.setJMSCorrelationID("myCorrelationID")

// create actor system with CamelExtension
val camel = CamelExtension(system)
val camelContext = camel.context
camelContext.addComponent("activemq", ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent(brokerURL))
val listener = system.actorOf(Props[Frontend])

// send a message, expect a response
producer.send(message)
val resp: TextMessage = respConsumer.receive(5000).asInstanceOf[TextMessage]
assert(resp.getText() == "polo")
```

I've tried two different approaches for the Consumer actor.  The first is simpler, which attempts to respond using `sender !`:

```
class Frontend extends Actor with Consumer {
  def endpointUri = "activemq:myapp.somequeue"
  override def autoAck = false
  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => {
      println("received %s" format msg.bodyAs[String])
      sender ! "polo"
    }
  }
}
```

The second attempts to reply using the CamelTemplate:

```
class Frontend extends Actor with Consumer {
  def endpointUri = "activemq:myapp.somequeue"
  override def autoAck = false
  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => {
      println("received %s" format msg.bodyAs[String])
      val replyTo = msg.getHeaderAs("JMSReplyTo", classOf[ActiveMQTempQueue], camelContext)
      val correlationId = msg.getHeaderAs("JMSCorrelationID", classOf[String], camelContext)
      camel.template.sendBodyAndHeader("activemq:"+replyTo.getQueueName(), "polo", "JMSCorrelationID", correlationId)
    }
  }
}
```

I do see the `println()` output from my actor's receive method, so the ActiveMQ message is getting into the actor, but I get a timeout on the `respConsumer.receive()` call in the testbench.  I've tried lots of combinations of specifying and not specifying headers in the reply.  I've also tried enabling and disabling `autoAck`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to call connection.start() in the JMS code.